# Proxy problem Gnome 3 and Chrome 12

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, gnome, gnome-3

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 and Gnome-3. I set the proxy settings through Gnome 3 new proxy manager but Chrome does not seem to like that and not using any proxy server.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add a proxy via Command-Parameter:

```
'--proxy-server="192.168.1.1:8080"'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is no way to add it like before?

Comment: sorry, don't know, but does this method help?

Answer (score 1):

After setting your proxy and "apply system wide" you need to open `configuration editor` (**gconf-editor**) and in **system > http_proxy** do followings:

`use_http_proxy` set to true(checked)

`use_same_proxy` set to true(checked)

if no such keys exist just create them by right clicking and selecting 'New key'. Chose boolean as type.

then go to chromium browser and navigate the net :)